# A question on pseudocompact space

Tags: general-topology, compactness

**The exercise is from the handbook of set-theoretic topology page 161:** Assume
$\mathfrak b=\mathfrak c$. 
Construct a first countable separable zero-dimensional locally compact pseudocompact space which is not countably compact but which has no uncountable closed discrete subset.

**The hint is given:** Fisrst construct a space first countable zero-dimensional locally compact space $X$ with underlying set $\mathfrak c$ such that $D=\{\xi: \omega\le \xi < \omega+\omega\}$ is a closed discrete set of cluster points of $\omega$ and such that each countably infinite subset of $X\setminus D$ has a cluster point.

Could anybody help me?

**Added:** $\mathfrak b$ is the [*bounding number*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinal_characteristic_of_the_continuum#Bounding_number_and_dominating_number):

$$\mathfrak b=\min\left\{|F|:F\subseteq{}^\omega\omega\text{ and }\forall f\in{}^\omega\omega\,\exists g\in F\left(g\not\le^* f\right)\right\}\;,$$

where $f\le^*g$ iff there is an $n\in\omega$ such that $f(k)\le g(k)$ for all $k\ge n$. That is, $\mathfrak b$ is the smallest cardinality of an unbounded set in the partial order $\left\langle{}^\omega\omega,\le^*\right\rangle$.